# catch is not catching the error Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a service that I am trying return an Observable if the response is a 401,403, or 500 like so:

```
  post(url, data) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers = this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
        return this.http.post(url, data, {
            headers: headers
        }).catch(this.catchAuthError(this));
    }
```

catchAuthError method:

```
    private catchAuthError (self: HttpUtil) {
        // we have to pass HttpService's own instance here as `self`
        return (res: Response) => {

            if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403 || res.status === 500) {

                //TODO: route the user to the login page again and make a 500 ERROR page
                // if not authenticated
                console.log("ERROR: "+res);

                this.relogin.showDialog();

            }
            return Observable.throw('Not authenticated: '+res);
        };
    }
```

I am not sure why the method is not being triggered but the network tab (chrome) will naturally tell me which error I got. However the console is not show `console.log("ERROR: "+res);`

Comment: AFAIK the error handler passed to `catch(...)` will get the error passed, not the `Response`. Have you checked? You also don't need to pass `this`/`self`, if you use arrow functions `this` will keep working in `catchAuthError` (like `}).catch((e) => this.catchAuthError(e));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your input parameter has a wrong type

Make sure that you are importing

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

Modify your code as below

```
 post(url, data) : Observable<Response> {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers = this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
        return this.http.post(url, data, {
            headers: headers
        }).map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.catchAuthError);
    }



private catchAuthError(res: Response) {
            if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403 || res.status === 500) {

            //TODO: route the user to the login page again and make a 500 ERROR page
            // if not authenticated
            console.log("ERROR: "+res);

            this.relogin.showDialog();

        }
        return Observable.throw('Not authenticated: '+res);

    }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/8FUckaMs1EZXHkxRZNTS?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be more like this:

```
post(url, data) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers = this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    return this.http.post(url, data, { headers: headers })
           .catch((err)=> this.catchAuthError(err)); //** use arrow notation here
}

private catchAuthError (error) {
    console.log(error); //**then depending on your error object fill the below lines
    if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403 || error.status === 500) {

        console.log("ERROR: "+ (error.message || error) );

        this.relogin.showDialog();
     }

     return Observable.throw('Not authenticated: '+error);
}
```